# Partial display failure

Tags: screen, hardware, broken-screen

The lower 1.5 to 2 cm of the screen of my OnePlus 3 failed:

[image: screen]

(The white part in the middle is just censored information. The problem only exists in the bottom.)

When I power my phone completely off,the part in the bottom is black and slowly turns green (but not uniformly green). There also is a colorful (now mostly white) line originating from the right side of the screen between the failed part of the screen and the part that works normally.

When I turn the display off, the failed part stays on a bit longer than the rest. When I turn it on again, it's green from the beginning if it has only been off for a few seconds. If it has been off for longer, it starts from being black. Probably just the same as if I turn it off completely because I waited before powering it up again.

Touch works normally anywhere on the screen. The buttons below the screen (return, home, app list) work normally too.

Is this a loose connection? Should I buy and install a new screen? How do I solve this problem?

I posted this on the OnePlus forum already (https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/partial-display-failure.882605/) and will answer this question myself if a solution is found there.

Comment: You can use adb's `dumpsys` utility to get more information about your display and maybe find the cause for this there.